# Django urls with the same name but different regexps

Tags: django, url, reverse

I have these types of urls:

```
/city/  
/city/category/  
/city/category/subcategory/
```

All of the urls are handling by one view. Is there a way to use the same name for these urls to subsequently use tags like these:

`{% url 'city_index' city.slug %}`,
`{% url 'city_index' city.slug category.slug %}`,
`{% url 'city_index' city.slug category.slug subcategory.slug %}`

I tried this:

```
url(r'^(?P<city_slug>[\w\-]+)/$',
    'real_city_index',
    name='city_index'
),
url(r'^(?P<city_slug>[\w\-]+)/(?P<category_slug>[\w\-]*)/{0,1}$',
    'real_city_index',
    name='city_index'
),
```

But in that case the second url reverse returns url without trailing slash.

If you do not write `/{0,1}`, urls like `/city/category` won't work, that is worse than reversing without slash.

Comment: I'm not sure to really understand your question, but there won't be slash if you don't put one before the $ character for the second url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django has [named URL patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns) for this. The problem with your code is that you use `city_index` for all of the url's `name` properties. Change these to `name='city_index'`, `name='city_category'` and `name='city_subcategory'` and all should be well. The view name (`real_city_index`) can be the same for all url patterns.

Comment: So you think there's no reason to use the same name for different urls?  
The code above works well. The only problem is that reversing of the second url returns url without slash at the end.  
Of course I could disregard this if there's no way to get it work.

Comment: I don't see a reason for it, no. You cannot define these different url generically (for all practical purposes), so you might as well name them differently anyway. This keeps things cleanly separated, so you do not mistakenly use a wrong combination of names and attributes. Naming them differently also allows you to use the trailing slash again.

Answer (score 5):

Is there a good reason not to call them 'city_index', 'city_index_with_category' and 'city_index_with_sub_category'?